# Can Mockito be used to match parameters that are functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I have a function with a prototype similar to:

```
class objectToMock {

    fun myFunc(stringArg: String, booleanArg: Boolean = false, functionArg: (String) -> Any = { 0 }): String

}
```

I'd like to be able to stub `myFunc` but can't figure out how to. Something like

```
@Mock
lateinit var mockedObject: ObjectToMock

@Before
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    `when`(mockedObject.myFunc(anyString(), anyBoolean(), any())).thenReturn("")
}
```

Using `any()` and `notNull()` both lead to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: any() must not be null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to use `anyOrNull` from https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin, or implement that helper yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito often returns `null` when calling methods like `any()`, `eq()` etcetera. Passing these instances to methods that are not properly mocked, can cause `NullPointerExceptions`

see: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
mockedObject = ObjectToMock()
```

@Before It is the place to initialize.
@Test It is the place to test.you can call mockedObject.myFunc()

Comment: I'm trying to mock the object, not instantiate it.